# showing all duplicate maximum values for every unique id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables of data that look like this:

table1:

```
 name | t2id  | percentage
-------------------------
  A   |  1    |    75
  B   |  1    |    75
  C   |  1    |    50
  D   |  2    |    30
  E   |  2    |    45
  F   |  2    |    45
  G   |  3    |    80
  H   |  3    |    70
  E   |  3    |    60
```

table2:

```
id  | name
-----------
 1  | NAME1
 2  | NAME2
 3  | NAME3
```

I got the max percentage for every t2id with the following:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, MAX(t1.percentage) AS MAX_p 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.t2id;
```

Output:

```
t1.name | t2.name | MAX_p
--------------------------
   A    |  NAME1  |  75
   E    |  NAME2  |  45
   G    |  NAME3  |  80
```

Now I'm also trying to show the duplicate maximum values for every t2id, something like this:

```
t1.name | t2.name | MAX_p
--------------------------
   A    |  NAME1  |  75
   B    |  NAME1  |  75
   E    |  NAME2  |  45
   F    |  NAME2  |  45
   G    |  NAME3  |  80
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this, I have been trying with subqueries but can't get it to show the correct output. If someone could help me out out with how I would go about doing this, it would be very much appreciated

Comment: Please tag your question with your RDBMS : Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, ms-Access, ...

Comment: Is the list in the bottom your desired output or what you get ? Since, `80` is not the member of duplicate maximum values.

Comment: Yes, the bottom output is what the output should be, where it gives the max percentage (also the duplicates) for every unique t2id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, t1.percentage AS MAX_p 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.t2id = t2.id
WHERE t1.percentage = (SELECT MAX(tt1.percentage)
                       FROM table1 tt1
                       WHERE tt1.t2id = t1.t2id
                      );
```

The advantage to this approach is performance -- it is not doing an aggregation on all the data.  In fact, with an index on `table1(t2id, percentage)`, the `WHERE` clause should be a fast table lookup.

This might be even faster written like this:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       (SELECT t2.name FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.t2id = t2.id) as t2_name,
       t1.percentage AS MAX_p 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.percentage = (SELECT MAX(tt1.percentage)
                       FROM table1 tt1
                       WHERE tt1.t2id = t1.t2id
                      );
```

This wants an index on `table2(id, name`.

This should essentially be a scan of `table1` with a fast index lookup on each row for filtering.  And then an additional index lookup on `table2` to get the name.

Comment: These only give one row of output (The same problem I had with my code). They give the correct output when I changed "MAX(t1.percentage) AS MAX_p" to "t1.percentage" though. Thanks!

Comment: @mathnz . . . Silly me.  There should be no aggregation going on in the outer query.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8 or later, then `RANK` can be used here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.name, t2.name AS t2name, t1.percentage,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t1.percentage DESC) rnk
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.t2id = t2.id
)

SELECT name, t2name, percentage
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

If you need a version which will run on MySQL versions earlier than 8, then we have to do more work:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name, t1.percentage
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.t2id = t2.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t2.id, MAX(t1.percentage) AS max_percentage
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.t2id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t2.id
) t3
    ON t2.id = t3.id AND t1.percentage = t3.max_percentage;
```

Comment: Since I'm using an older version second solution worked,also the third inner join can be left out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is standard SQL and will work with all versions of MySQL (and other RDBMS)

```
SELECT t1.name AS t1name, t2.name AS t2name, t1.percentage
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT t2id, MAX(percentage) AS MAX_p 
     FROM table1 t1
     GROUP BY t2id) m
  ON t1.t2id = m.t2id AND t1.percentage=m.MAX_p
```

Comment: (SELECT t1.t2id, MAX(t1.percentage) AS MAX_p 
     FROM table1 t1

Comment: Also "table1 t1" and then it works perfectly :) thanks